Modern troops going into barbarian land
So this movie is about two 8-wheeled vehicles (I think it's military plus scientist) going through a long wall dividing its land with an unknown land. 
After that I remember that there were body bags that were see through in the vehicles and the people that came in the vehicles were catching the native people and placing them in there. Inside one of those bags was a girl and using a blade she cut through the bag and slits the throat of the driver while the soldiers were out fighting for their lives. I think these native people were cannibals and I remember a scene where a soldier is burnt white crisp and eaten by these natives.
I also remember motorcycle scenes.

Doomsday. It matches everything you described
From IMDB

A lethal virus spreads throughout Scotland, infecting millions and killing hundreds of thousands. To contain the threat, acting authorities brutally quarantine the country as it succumbs to fear and chaos. The quarantine is successful. Three decades later, the Reaper virus violently resurfaces in London. An elite group of specialists, including Eden Sinclair, is urgently dispatched into Scotland to retrieve a cure by any means necessary. Shut off from the rest of the world, the unit must battle through a landscape that has become a waking nightmare





Holy macaroni you are right. this was the movie I saw when I was a kid! thanks man I appreciate it!!!!!!!

Glad I could help
